# Firebase - How can I retrieve the objects in a date range?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the next JSON structure in Firebase:

```
{
  "-KGX6kYg1NO6d9hn-8um" : {
    "phase" : "A",
    "timestamp" : "12-18-2015 19:43:37"
  },
  "-KGXOGSxa3vompZX9UO_" : {
    "phase" : "B",
    "timestamp" : "03-28-2016 15:28:21"
  },
  "-KMUvszD-vm3Nu02sofd" : {
    "phase" : "A",
    "timestamp" : "04-03-2014 03:57:56"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to filter the objects by the timestamp key through a range of date?.. For example, I want to get the objects with timestamp from January 2015 to today date. If not possible, what's the better way to filter the objects by dates?... I'm developing an iOS app.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you could store the timestamp as unix timestamp instead of date format. In that case filtering based on timestamp would be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort the snapshot data by `timestamp` and define a `timestamp` limit from which you want your data.
For example you want all data from a specific timestamp `timestamp1`, your reference handler should look like:

```
let refHandle = tableRef.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp").queryEndingAtValue("timestamp1").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            for item in snapshot.children {

            }
        })
```

You can also apply number of records that you want by adding `queryLimitedToLast` or `queryLimitedToFirst` like :

```
  let refHandle = tableRef.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp").queryEndingAtValue("some_time_stamp").queryLimitedToLast(kPostLimit + 1).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            for item in snapshot.children {

            }
        })
```

Also, you want to have a look at the following [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html) about common sql queries in Firebase.