# Swift Only display dates that have passed

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am retrieving data from Firebase which include dates. I want to only show items that the dates have already been. At the moment dates are shown if the day of the month has passed e.g if the date is 25/02/17 then dates of the 26th and onwards wont show but dates lower than the 25th will despite what the month is. So how can i get it to take into account the month and year as well?

Below is my current code.

```
   func setupAgendaData() {
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    print(userID)
    ref.child("users").child(userID!).child("Agenda").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.agenda.removeAll()
        print(snapshot)
        for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            if let dictionary = item.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let agendaItem = Agenda()
                agendaItem.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
                self.agenda.append(agendaItem)

            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        })

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

 /*   let actDate = ActDate()
    let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
    actDate.date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    //if self.agenda < actDate.date {
        print(agenda.count)
  //  }
   print(agenda.count)
 */
  return agenda.count
   }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let previousCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(previousCellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PreviousCell

    let actDate = ActDate()
    let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
    actDate.date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    let filtAgenda = agenda[indexPath.item].date < actDate.date
    if filtAgenda == true {

    previousCell.nameLabel.text = agenda[indexPath.item].activity
    previousCell.timeLabel.text = agenda[indexPath.item].time
    previousCell.dateLabel.text = agenda[indexPath.item].date

    }


    return previousCell

    }
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to compare date strings instead of actual `Date` instances?

Comment: Just the way i though to do it, how would you recommend then?

Comment: Do you need all the data from Agenda? If not you can filter them using Firebase [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413752/firebase-how-can-i-retrieve-the-objects-in-a-date-range)

Comment: @Darren As I said, you need to compare the actual `Date` objects, not strings.

Comment: @maddy Thank you i have done this now and everything is working as it should

Comment: @Darren convert your NSDate in a TimeStamp and save it as a String in Firebase. When you read from Firebase, you will get an array with a snapshot which will contain all objects you saved in your database, then you can sort the array in place using `sort(by:_,_)` method giving it as argument timestamp retrieved from Firebase and finally filter filter each element in the array against the condition specified in the body of the closure.